# Alternative to cp command since cp throws warnings and returns with error code while used with NFS

Tags: nfs, cp

I was using the following copy command to take backup of my datastore

`cp -pr $src $dest`

Which gives me the following warning while using with NFS and returns an error code but the files are actually getting copied.

`cp: preserving times for ‘$src/file1’: Invalid argument`

Is there any alternative method to do this? I want to get rid of the warnings and wrong return code. I do not care about preserving time stamps, but other attributes such as mode and ownership should be preserved.

Comment: You could use `tar` instead and have it preserve the permissions etc. of the source files in the archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page for `cp` shows that there are options available to control which attributes are included.

> **`-p`** same as `--preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps`
>
> **`--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]`**  preserve the specified attributes (default: `mode,ownership,timestamps`), if possible additional attributes: `context, links, xattr, all`

It follows, therefore, that you could follow `-p` with something like `--no-preserve=timestamps`.